# Threads stopped after function return

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, threadpool

I'm trying to create several thread workers in a function called `engine_setup`, but every time the function returns, every thread stops as well. I tried to create pthread id as global pointer but didn't help. 
here's the global:`pthread_t * threadIDs;`
the engine_setup function:

```
query_helper* engine_setup(size_t n_processors) {
    //some code that is not relevant
    int err;
    threadIDs=malloc(n_processors*sizeof(*threadIDs));
    for(int i=0;i<n_processors;i++){
      err = pthread_create(&threadIDs[i],NULL,tp,(void*)helper);
      if (err != 0)
      printf("can't create thread \n");
    }
    printf("end setup\n");
    return helper;
}
```

and the thread function pointer is here:

```
void* tp(void * ptr){
    query_helper * helper=(query_helper*)ptr;
    while(1){
        printf("1\n");
    }
}
```

the output is something like this:

```
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
1
end setup
```

which shows that all the threads stopped when engine_setup return. Is there a way to keep them running?

Comment: What is your main thread doing after `engine_setup` exits?

Comment: @Angew so far my main thread just call `query_helper helper=*engine_setup(4);`

Comment: Please post a [mcve]. BTW, if your `main` exits right after `engine_setup` is called, then your program will indeed terminate (including all threads in it).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can call pthread_join(threadIds[i],null); (for all threads i), which will wait until the thred function returns.

You can use the second argument for storing return value from thread.
I.e:

```
void *results[n_processors];
for(int i=0; i<n_processors; i++){
    pthread_join(threadIds[i], &results[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Does your program exit after the function returns?  If so you'd want to use pthread_join on each thread so that the program will wait for each thread to terminate before exiting.